# How to remove observer defined without object and using block?

Tags: ios, swift, observer-pattern, nsnotificationcenter

Within `extension UIViewController` I have a method:

```
func setupUserAndCartButtons() {

    let cartBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: DBCart.sharedCart().icon, style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("cartButtonTapped:"))

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(DBOrdersChangedNotficationName, object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: { [weak self] notification in
        print("---->\(self!.classForCoder)")
        cartBarButtonItem.image = DBCart.sharedCart().icon
    })
}
```

I use it to change the image for my `UIBarButtonItem`.

This is how I push notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(DBOrdersChangedNotficationName, object: nil)
```

For every controller, within deinit, I need to remove observer:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: DBOrdersChangedNotficationName, object: nil)
```

But it doesn't work:

When I push notification and `deinit` is never called (what means that I never pop controller from the stack) it looks ok, no crash, but once I pop at least one view controller (deinit is called then) and push notification, there is a crash:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: What do you mean with it doesn't work? Is `deinit` called?

Comment: the closure version of `addObserverForName` returns an object, which will be the observer, and you have to store that, and remove that in the deinit from the `NSNotificationCenter`, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891229/remove-observer-when-using-addobserverfornameusingblock

Answer (score 2):

You are using `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` to setup your observer. In order to later remove this observer you will need to use the **return value** of that method as the "observer" in any calls to the `removeObserver:...` variants.

Since you are setting up the observer in an extension method of `UIViewController`, and assuming you are calling this from concrete `UIViewController` subclasses, I'd suggest updating this method to return the observer

```
func setupUserAndCartButtons() -> NSObjectProtocol {

    let cartBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: DBCart.sharedCart().icon, style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("cartButtonTapped:"))

    let observer = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(DBOrdersChangedNotficationName, object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: { [weak self] notification in
        print("---->\(self!.classForCoder)")
        cartBarButtonItem.image = DBCart.sharedCart().icon
    })

    return observer
}
```

You will have to setup a property in your view controllers where you make use of this method in order to keep a reference to the observer:

```
class DBSomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var ordersChangedObserver: NSObjectProtocol?

    ...
}
```

Then assign the return value of `setupUserAndCartButtons` to this property:

```
ordersChangedObserver = setupUserAndCartButtons()
```

And finally remove the observer in the `deinit`:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(ordersChangedObserver)
}
```

**Credit**

I can't take full credit for this answer as [Dániel Nagy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592349/d%C3%A1niel-nagy) pretty much got it in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718527/how-to-remove-observer-defined-without-object-and-using-block#comment51374174_31718527) on the question.